# Cant display a linked list properly with char

Tags: c++, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, c-strings

Recordlabel.cpp

```
void recordLabel::addArtist(char* artistName)
    {
        Node* temp = new Node;                  
        temp->artistName = artistName;         
        temp->next = head;                     
        head = temp;                            
        
    }
    
    void recordLabel::displayArtists()
    {
        Node* tmp = head;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            cout << tmp->artistName << " ";
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }

Main.cpp

    int main()
    {
        recordLabel recordLabel;
        
        char* artistName = new char[25];
        char repeatLoop = 'y';
    
        while (repeatLoop == 'y' || repeatLoop == 'Y')
        {
            cout << "Please Enter an Artist Name: ";
            cin.getline(artistName,25);
    
            recordLabel.addArtist(artistName);
            
  
            cout << "Do you want to add a Name? (y/n): ";
            cin >> repeatLoop;
    
            cin.ignore();
        }
        
        recordLabel.displayArtists();
         
    
        //delete[] artistName;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

So I'm trying to display my linked list but when I enter input like "john" "kyle" "david" the output from the display function justs ends up being david david david. Can someone help me with this? Also, I realize using string would solve most of my problems but I'm trying to just use Chars.

Thanks

Comment: Some things to think about: When you call `addArtist` what is the pointer you pass to it? How does this pointer differ between calls? What happens with the string it points to inside the function?

Comment: @Anti CS Guru You need to create a copy of the string passed to the function through the parameter artistName in each node of the list.

Comment: Hint: your linked list nodes don't have strings in them.

Answer (score 0):

All nodes of the list contain in their data members `artistName` the address of the allocated memory stored in the pointer  `artistName` declared in `main`.

```
char* artistName = new char[25];
//...
recordLabel.addArtist(artistName);
```

and

```
void recordLabel::addArtist(char* artistName)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;                  
    temp->artistName = artistName;
    //...
```

That is all the data members store the address of the same allocated memory.

As a result all the data members will point to the last string stored in this dynamically allocated memory.

You need to crate a copy of the stored string in the current moment.

For example

```
#include <cstring>

//...

void recordLabel::addArtist( const char *artistName )
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->artistName = new char[strlen( artistName ) + 1];            
    strcpy( temp->artistName, artistName );         
    temp->next = head;                     
    head = temp;                            
}
```

When you should free all the allocated memory for strings and nodes in the destructor of the list.

Also it is unclear why the output of the list starts from the second node

```
void recordLabel::displayArtists()
{
    Node* tmp = head;
    tmp = tmp->next;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    //...
```

If initially the pointer head is equal to `nullptr` then the function can invoke undefined behavior when will be called for an empty list.

You could make your life easier if the data member `artistName` had the type `std::string` instead of `char *`.

For example if the class Node is defined something like

```
struct Node
{
    std::string artistName;
    Node *next;
}
```

then the member function `addArtist` could look very simply.

```
#include <string>

//...

void recordLabel::addArtist( const char *artistName )
{
    head = new Node { artistName, head };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Also I think the reason why the output is starting from the 2nd node is because after assigning tmp to head the next line then sets tmp to the next node (tmp= tmp->next) before outputting anything.

Comment: @AntiCSGuru You are wrong. The head node pointes to the current actual node. So the output shall start from the head node.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the method `addArtist` in this way:

```cpp
void recordLabel::addArtist(char* artistName)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->artistName = strdup(artistName);
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

You need to include also `string.h`

```
#include <cstring>
```

Do not forget to clean the memory with the destructor